# An unrecoverable error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator newsfeed webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint online. when I tried to upload a file in newsfeed web part. I am getting the following error

> "An unrecoverable error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator."

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your MySite configured properly.
2. Check My Site host location configured properly in central admin
3. Check the configuration of your Web-Applications and the App-Pools (that the same service account used for My Site and Intranet web app-pools).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The error also occurs when any user tries to upload his profile picture in his MySite.

**Resolution**
In my case, the root MySite quota got full. Hence Newsfeed or Profile pictures were not getting uploaded. Solution is to increase the quota for root site collection of your MySite web app from Central admin.